# List<int> : Linq get list per item

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to get this query in Linq to (Microsoft)SQL.

```
SELECT        MAX(ID) AS MyValue
FROM            Table
WHERE    "list contains 1 or 2 or 3"
```

How can I do this?
The only examples I see around are only resulting in the max on the entire column and not per group (Example where TogetherId = 1)

I'd like to get a result like:
Rows:

```
TogetherId | Id
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 16
2 | 7
3 | 8
3 | 9
```

Result:

```
TogetherId | Id
1 | 16
2 | 7
3 | 9
```

How can I do this with Linq?

```
List<int> myList; // Consider the list to be populated.
```

I'm already using this piece for the Where -> `where myList.Contains(MyTable.ID)`

I only want to select 1 column to a String-list in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
myList = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.TogetherId)
                 .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).First())
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want something like a `GroupBy` followed by a `Max`:

```
 var newList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.TogetherId, x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => new {
                  TogetherId = x.Key,
                  MaxId = x.Max()
             })
            .ToList();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LROWSF91311

Answer (score 0):

```
list
.GroupBy(x => x.TogetherId)
.Select(g => new { TogetherId = g.Key, Max = g.Max(x => x.Id) });
```

Answer (score 0):

and variant with query syntax

```
myList = (from x in yourList
         group x by x.TogetherId into g
         select new {
             TogetherId = g.Key, 
             Max = g.Max(a=>a.Id)
         }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(2);

List<String> myList1 = MyTable.Where(x=> myList.Contains(x.TogetherId)).GroupBy(x => x.TogetherId)
                            .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).First().Id))
                            .ToList();
```